# shp2pgql: how to omit the git column?

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I am importing a series of shapefiles with `shp2pqsql` that already have a unique identifier attribute. Since `shp2pqsql` creates a new column called `gid` I am ending up with two unique identifiers per record.

Is there any way to tell `shp2pqsql` to omit the creation of the `gid` column? Or better still, to use the existing identifying attribute instead ?

**Update**: I have `shp2pqsql` version *2.1.2 (r12389)* installed. I am using it like:

`shp2pgsql Roads.shp roads > load_roads.sql`

Comment: What version are you using? What command are you running. In principle the gid column is not imported.

Comment: Since you're just getting SQL out, why not simply remove the delcaration that creates the `gid` field? e.g. `shp2pgsql Roads.shp roads | sed "s/gid serial,//" > load_roads.sql`

Comment: Hi Arthur, that is precisely what I have been doing. But wouldn't it be nice if there was a way of avoiding that extra task?